# In Spring MVC is it possible to access spring properties file directly from the view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a properties file contain a few values.  I can inject those values into a controller with @Value then pass the value into a view.

My question is how do I access the properties value without the controller?  let's say if I want to use a tag and access the properties values within the tag thus I don't have the controller to pass down the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it which comes to my mind is use `spring:message` It probably should work but looks like a hack and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, the sprng:message serve the purpose of localization, not configuring application logic